# Получение asset-а префаба

Tags: unity3d, assets, prefabs

На данный момент мой метод выглядит следующим образом:

```
public static void MethodName<T>(T asset) where T : Object
{
    //Получаем оригинал объекта. Если метод вернул null - значит asset и есть оригинал
    T origin = PrefabUtility.GetCorrespondingObjectFromOriginalSource(asset) ?? asset;
    //Получаем путь до объекта 
    var path = AssetDatabase.GetAssetPath(origin);
    ...
}
```

Столкнулся с некоторой проблемой после перехода на Unity 2018.3 - в ней юнитеки обновили систему префабов и закономерно сломали всё, что с ней было связано.

Когда мы присылаем в этот метод инстанс префаба на сцене - всё работает нормально, т.к. оригинал находится и можно получить путь до него.

Но вот если править префаб в новой специальной сцене для префабов всё идёт совсем плохо. Т.к. на этой сцене находится не инстанс, а сам "префаб" в понимании юнити, то метод возвращает null, но при этом asset продолжает ссылаться на объект со сцены и при запросе пути до него возвращает `string.Empty` т.к. файлового пути у объекта на сцене быть не может.

Раньше, когда объект просто выделялся в папке с файлами и рисовался в инспекторе всё работало нормально, т.к. ассет ссылался на конкретный файл в папке, а не на сцену.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Разобрался в конечном итоге.

Теперь у Unity появился волшебный `namespace UnityEditor.Experimental.SceneManagement`, в котором есть класс `PrefabStageUtility`позволяющий получать некоторую информацию из текущей "префаб-сцены", например, текущее её состояние - `PrefabStage`, в котором уже и лежит множество интересных полей, например, так нужный мне `prefabAssetPath`.

Именно через эту утилиту частично работает вся сцена и идёт сохранение префаба. (Пришлось для этого выкачивать исходники Unity и искать редактор этой сцены).